# Using two data-toggle for same element in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was messing around with Bootstrap and created a page which has a simple navigation menu. I wanted to add modal for one of the links, which already has a `tooltip`.

And I did add the modal to `li` like this,

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SettingsModal" data-toggle="tooltip"
```

Surprisingly, its working. It doesn't make much sense. Because at least one `data-toggle` has to be neglected.

I know that it is better to wrap it inside an element which has `tooltip`. My question is, how is this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working because the Bootstrap [data attributes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-data-attrs) use separate jQuery selectors to "activate" the various components.

Since 
`$('[data-toggle="modal"]')` and `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')` are both referenced in the Bootstrap JS code, both modal and tooltip components are working.

Comment: awsome and fast response